# No transport available socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Check out the error in socket.io.js + node.js
[image]

Comment: Are you specifying which transports to use in your code?
What version of socket.io & node are you using?
(Some code would be helpful)

Comment: Ya we are defining 'transports':'xhr-multipart' and we are using 0.6.2 version of socket.io.js

Comment: Is this issue happening only in Firefox?

Comment: Ya in Google chrome same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code

```
var socket = new io.Socket('uwtech.nodester.com',{'port':80,'transports':'xhr-multipart'});
```

Try to add more transports

Xhr-multipart protocol availability checked by string:

```
'XMLHttpRequest' in window && 'prototype' in XMLHttpRequest && 'multipart' in XMLHttpRequest.prototype
```

try to log it's result.

Comment: It works on the machine from which it is developed (i mean to say where the coder has coded it) but then why it does not works from other machine.  I appreciate you help and +1 for that.Answer me this and I select your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are specifying transports correctly? The error you are receiving only occurs when socket.io cannot find any listed transports..

```
if (!this.transport && 'console' in window) console.error('No transport available');
```

Try doing something like this...  (not specifying any transports)

```
var socket= new io.Socket('yourhost.com')
```

and see if you are still having issues

Comment: Not only find, but can't use too.